# Using fopen to download files isn't working with certain file names

Tags: php, download, fopen

I've written some code to download our policy documents from our other server:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($newObject->policies); $i++) {
    $newPolicy = $newObject->policies[$i];
    $newPolicy->name = htmlspecialchars_decode(preg_replace("/(.*?)(\W+)?$/", "$1", $newPolicy->name)); //Fixes &amp; etc, removes trailing spaces/dots/etc
    $filePath = sprintf("../../Intranet Docs/Policies/%s/%s", $newPolicy->name, $newPolicy->version);
    $fileName = sprintf("%s/%s", $filePath, $newPolicy->filename);

    if(!file_exists($fileName)) {
        if(!file_exists($filePath)) {
            mkdir($filePath, 0777, true);
        }
        $downloadLink = sprintf("http://xxx/jhoots/documents/%s", rawurlencode($newPolicy->filename));
        file_put_contents($fileName, fopen($downloadLink, 'r'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now, this code works fine for 90% of the documents.

However, when I hit a document that has a name like this:

> Jhoots FD SOP 27.01a Bank Supplier Payments (Direct Debits, Standing Orders & BACs) SAGE Inputting Procedure.pdf

I get the following warning:

> Warning: file_put_contents(../../Intranet Docs/Policies/Jhoots FD SOP 27.01a Bank Supplier Payments (Direct Debits, Standing Orders & BACs) SAGE Inputting Procedure/27.01a/Jhoots FD SOP 27.01a Bank Supplier Payments (Direct Debits, Standing Orders & BACs) SAGE Inputting Procedure.pdf) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I had this issue with a lot of the other documents, but fixed it by implementing the `rawurlencode` method for the `downloadLink` variable.

I know it has SOMETHING to do with how it's encoding the name, but I can't quite figure it out.

If I echo the download link, and open it in my browser, it finds the document just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this happen with all filenames that have spaces in the filename?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, it doesn't.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: Did you check the mkdir call actually succeeded? So the folder structure up to and including `Intranet Docs/Policies/Jhoots FD SOP 27.01a Bank Supplier Payments (Direct Debits, Standing Orders & BACs) SAGE Inputting Procedure/27.01a/` exists now, when you try to write that file?

Comment: Does it happen to all filenames with a `(` in them?

Comment: @04FS Yes, both directories get created.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It seems that way, yes.

Comment: And `&` can be a little dodgy in linux as well. There must be a unix/linux "Chars not to use in filenames" reference somewhere. But if you wrap the name in Quotes it will create the file

Comment: Hmm, actually I think it's the `,` and `:`. But you're allowed `,` in a directory name.

Comment: No ubuntu at least seems to allow a `,` and a `:` in a file name for some wierd reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many headaches, I figured out the problem was the length of the file name when I tried to go into the directory and save it manually. I have since used an ID for one of the directories and it works fine.